# Simulate partial type parameter inference with implicits?

Tags: scala

I'm making a simple dependency injection framework, for constructor injection, in Scala. The idea is that objects that are DI'd put their required services in their constructor like regular parameters, and implement a typeclass that determines which of their arguments are taken from the container and which are passed by the user on instantiation.

So, it should look something like:

```
trait Container {
  private singletons: Map[Class, AnyRef]
  def getSingleton[T: Manifest] =
    singletons(implicitly[Manifest[T]].erasure).asInstanceOf[T]
  ... methods for adding singletons, etc ...
}

class Foo(arg: String, svc: FooService) {
  ...
}

trait Constructor[T] { ??? }    

object FooConstructor extends Constructor[Foo] {
  def construct(arg: String)(implicit container: Container) =
    new Foo(arg, container.getSingleton[FooService])
}
```

Now basically I'd like to be able to have a method called `construct`, which I can call as `construct[Foo]("asd")` and get a new instance of `Foo` with `"asd"` passed in to the constructor, and `FooService` gotten from the local container and passed in to the constructor. The idea is that it should grab the instance of the `Constructor` type class for `Foo` and in a typesafe way, know the number and types of arguments it should have. Also, and this is the hard part, I don't want to have to write out the types of the arguments - just the object to be constructed.

I've tried a couple things:

```
trait Constructor1[T, A] {
  def construct(arg: A): T
}

trait Constructor2[T, A1, A2] {
  def construct(arg1: A1, arg2: A2): T
}

def construct[T, A](arg1: A): T = implicitly[Constructor1[T, A]].construct(arg1)

...
```

This approach doesn't work though because it seems like in order to "summon" the `Constructor` type class instance, we need to write the types of the arguments, which is a lot of nasty boilerplate:

```
construct[Foo, String]("asd") // yuck!
```

Is there a way to use type classes (or anything else) to sort of partially infer the type parameters? We have the types of the constructor parameters for `Foo` defined in the `Constructor` instance definition, so if we can summon the instance we should be able to just call `construct` and get the right argument types. The issue is getting that instance without having to specify the constructor type arguments. I've played around with a bunch of different ideas for this, and I feel like with Scala's power and bag of tricks there just *has* to be a way I can write `construct[Foo]("asd")` and have the argument list be type safe. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Thanks to Miles Sabin's excellent answer + a slight modification, here's a method that only requires one type parameter and works for all different argument list lengths. This is a pretty simple way to painlessly wire up dependencies, without the cost of reflection:

```
trait Constructor1[T, A] { def construct(arg1: A)(implicit c: Container): T }
trait Constructor2[T, A, B] { def construct(arg1: A, arg2: B)(implicit c: Container): T }

implicit object FooConstructor extends Constructor1[Foo, String] {
  def construct(arg1: String)(implicit c: Container) = 
    new Foo(arg1, c.getSingleton[FooService])
}

implicit object BarConstructor extends Constructor2[Bar, String, Int] {
  def construct(arg1: String, arg2: Int)(implicit c: Container) = 
    new Bar(arg1, arg2, c.getSingleton[FooService])
}

class Construct[T] {
  def apply[A](arg1: A)(implicit ctor: Constructor1[T, A], container: Container) =
    ctor.construct(arg1)
  def apply[A, B](arg1: A, arg2: B)(implicit ctor: Constructor2[T, A, B], container: Container) =
    ctor.construct(arg1, arg2)
}

def construct[T] = new Construct[T]

construct[Foo]("asd")
construct[Bar]("asd", 123)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type parameter inference in Scala is an all or nothing affair: if you explicitly supply any of the type arguments for a type parameter block then you must supply them all. Consequently, if you want to supply only some of a set of type arguments you must arrange for them to belong to separate type parameter blocks.

The way to do that in this case is to split the `construct` method into two stages: the first, which takes an explicit type argument and returns a function-like value; and a second, which applies the function-like value to the arguments for which you want the types to be inferred.

Here's how it might go,

```
// Function-like type
class Construct1[T] {
  def apply[A](arg1: A)(implicit ctor : Constructor1[T, A]): T =
    ctor.construct(arg1)
}

def construct[T] = new Construct1[T]
```

The result of invoking `construct[Foo]` is a value of type `Construct1[Foo]`. This has an `apply` method with a type parameter, which can be inferred, and an implicit parameter whose type is determined by both `T` and `A`. The invocation you want to make now looks like,

```
construct[Foo].apply("asd")  // T explicit, A inferred as String
```

Scala's semantic sugaring rules around `apply` applies here which mean that this can be rewritten as,

```
construct[Foo]("asd")
```

which is exactly the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I was kinda hoping you would take a look at it... Sorry the question was so long! Unfortunately, this doesn't quite solve the problem yet, because I can't make overloading for different arg list lengths work. Using this approach, I'd have to say `construct1[Foo]("asd")`, `construct2[Bar]("asd", 123)`, etc. I've tried adding an implicit evidence parameter to differentiate overloads of `construct` (`construct[T](implicit ev: Constructor[T,_,_])`, etc.), but it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: I solved it! The trick is to not have a `Construct1[T]` object, but just a `Construct[T]` object, that has all the "apply" methods, one for each argument list length. I'll update my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
trait Construct[T, A] {
 def apply(arg: A): T
}

class Constructor[T]{
  def apply[A](arg : A)(implicit construct : Construct) = construct(arg)
}

object Constructor {
 def apply[T] = new Constructor[T]
}

Constructor[T]("arg")
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the accepted answer (which is two years older) except that this one doesn't even compile and has no explanation.