# How to infer types when one is a return value?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to define a method which is generic both in its parameter and return type. Basically to make a helper function for JSON serialization to/from case classes.

so I want to write something like this pseudocode:

```
def post[Request,Response](data:Request) : Response = ???

case class A(i:String)
case class B(j:Int)

val result = post[A,B]("input")
```

in this case (assuming no errors) *result* is of type B.

It's understandable that the compiler can't infer the return value, but I'd like it to infer the Request type. In other words I'd like to write something like

```
val result = post[B]("input")
```

where the type of A is inferred by the *data* parameter, so the user need only specify the return type when calling the function.

Comment: I'm hoping there's an answer that's not so complex. At this point I'm thinking it's easier to just supply both type parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know many details of Scala specifically, but in Haskell that ability is enabled by a compiler option called "Functional dependencies", whereby you have a typeclass with two type variables, one of which can be derived from the other - see section 7.4.3 of http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6/html/users_guide/type-extensions.html. Obviously you can't just use this feature, since it's in a different language, but knowing what it's called should help you find a solution. For example, [Functional dependencies in Scala](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/) looks like a good guess; although again, I don't know enough Scala to read that article and then tell you exactly how to answer your original JSON question.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @amalloy's answer, and the link he provides, the Scala equivalent for what you are trying to achieve would be something like the following:

```
trait ReqResp[Request,Response] {
  def apply(req: Request): Response
}

def post[Request,Response](data:Request)(implicit rr: ReqResp[Request,Response]): Response = rr(data)

case class A(i:String)
case class B(j:Int)

implicit object reqRespAB extends ReqResp[A,B] {
  def apply(a: A) = B(a.i.toInt)
}

val result = post(A("456"))
```

This gives the output:

```
result: B = B(456)
```

Comment: Is this also a way to attach it? Which would you recommend? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726222/simulate-partial-type-parameter-inference-with-implicits?rq=1